# UITableViewCell image async queue caching not working properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, caching, asynchronous

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code. It seems to work but when I scroll fast and then stop, the UIImageView cycles through a few pictures before displaying the correct one. This happens quickly but noticeable.

```
if (![post objectForKey:@"photoData"] && ![post objectForKey:@"isDownloadingPhoto"]){
    cell.instagramPhoto.image = nil;
    [[combinedArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] setObject:@"loading" forKey:@"photoData"];
    [[combinedArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] setObject:@"yes" forKey:@"isDownloadingPhoto"];
    [cell.instagramPhoto setAlpha:0];
    if (instagramURL != nil){
        dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{
            int index = indexPath.row;
            NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: instagramURL];
            if (data.length > 0){
                [[combinedArray objectAtIndex:index] setObject:data forKey:@"photoData"];
                [[combinedArray objectAtIndex:index] setObject:@"no" forKey:@"isDownloadingPhoto"];
                UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
                dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    cell.instagramPhoto.image = image;
                    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
                    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
                    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.4f];
                    cell.instagramPhoto.alpha = 1.0;
                    [UIView commitAnimations];
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
else if ([[post valueForKey:@"isDownloadingPhoto"] isEqualToString:@"yes"]) {
    NSLog(@"loading");
    cell.instagramPhoto.image = nil;
}
else {
    NSData *data = [post valueForKey:@"photoData"];
    NSLog(@"saved");
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
    cell.instagramPhoto.image = image;
}
```

Comment: And all this inside `cellForIndexPath`?

Comment: Yeah all inside cellForRowIndexPath

Comment: And you also have some cell reuse logic inside presumable. I suspect this is what's happening - `cellForIndex...` gets called for a cell, you start async download process, scroll table view and this cell gets reused inside another `cellForIndex`

Comment: Is there any way to avoid this? If not what is the recommended way to cache images in a tableviewCell?

Comment: Let me wrap it into an answer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Looks like this code is executed inside `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath`. And if you have any cell reusing logic here - you might have problems when cell will be reused before current async image download operation to this cell is complete.

You need to be able to abort these download tasks if cell is being reused before they complete.

** UPDATE **

There are couple ways you can implement it:

- The easiest one (and probably most memory-consuming) - make sure you're generating unique cellId for each cell, so there will not be any reuse of already allocated cells. It will be slower, but you will have guarantee that operation you started will finish on the same cell you started it.
- Check that cell is the same after your download is complete. You can for example at the beginning of your code assign `tag` for the cell to its row number.

  cell.tag = indexPath.row

Then save it off before starting `dataWithContext` call and check after.

```
int oldTag = cell.tag;
dataWithContext...
if (cell.tag != oldTag) {
   // Don't so any image update
}
```

- Change dataWithContext to something async so you can actually break and abort the download process. I'm not sure how to proceed with this one - it will require a bit more of research.

Comment: I'm completely clueless on how to detect if a cell is being reused before the download completes. Do you have any ideas on how this would be accomplished?

Comment: That's part easy enough. Subclass `UITableViewCell` and define `ready` property in your class. Set that property to YES from the async download when it's complete.

Comment: Im sorry, I don't think Im understanding correctly. Wouldn't doing that be the same as setting the image from the async?

Comment: You can use image property (whether it's nil or not) as well. The main question should be - how to abort the download task from my viewpoint.

Comment: That is my question, how does the ready property allow me to abort the download?